# How to draw 2 cubes instead fo one? (DirectX9)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx

Here my code draws one cube:

```
void CreateCube(
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 &ptr_dxDevice, 
    LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 &ptr_indexBuffer, 
    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 &ptr_vertexBuffer,
    int cubeNumber
)
{
    // create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX struct
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        { -0.2f,  0.2f, -0.2f, 0xffff0000,},
        {  0.2f,  0.2f, -0.2f, 0xff00ff00,},
        { -0.2f, -0.2f, -0.2f, 0xffff0000,},
        {  0.2f, -0.2f, -0.2f, 0xff00ff00,},
        { -0.2f,  0.2f,  0.2f, 0xffff0000,},
        {  0.2f,  0.2f,  0.2f, 0xff00ff00,},
        { -0.2f, -0.2f,  0.2f, 0xffff0000,},
        {  0.2f, -0.2f,  0.2f, 0xff00ff00,},
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    ptr_dxDevice->CreateVertexBuffer(
        8 * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
        0,
        drawFVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &ptr_vertexBuffer,
        NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    ptr_vertexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    ptr_vertexBuffer->Unlock();

    // create the indices using an int array
    short indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,    // side 1
        2, 1, 3,
        4, 0, 6,    // side 2
        6, 0, 2,
        7, 5, 6,    // side 3
        6, 5, 4,
        3, 1, 7,    // side 4
        7, 1, 5,
        4, 5, 0,    // side 5
        0, 5, 1,
        3, 7, 2,    // side 6
        2, 7, 6,
    };

    // create an index buffer interface called i_buffer
    ptr_dxDevice->CreateIndexBuffer(36 * sizeof(short),
        0,
        D3DFMT_INDEX16,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &ptr_indexBuffer,
        NULL);


    // lock i_buffer and load the indices into it
    ptr_indexBuffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
    ptr_indexBuffer->Unlock();

    ptr_dxDevice->SetFVF(drawFVF);

    // select the vertex and index buffers to use
    ptr_dxDevice->SetStreamSource(0, vertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));
    ptr_dxDevice->SetIndices(ptr_indexBuffer);

    // draw the cube
    ptr_dxDevice->DrawIndexedPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 0, 8, 0, 12);
}
```

When I tries to use this code to create 2 or more cubes I got memory violation error. I'm using vertex bufefr and index Buffer.

PLease,  help me to fix this code - what should I do to be able to draw 2 or more cubes ?

Thank you

P.S.
Using DirectX9
Visual Studio 2017
Today is Thursday

Comment: Show what you changed for two cubes.

Comment: I used this method twicely. The diffreence only in coordinates. And I got memory violation  error

Comment: @BenVoigt  Is it possible to use vertexBuffer/indexBuffer mpore then 1 time?

Comment: You can have more than one vertexBuffer and more than one index buffer.  Or you can make each buffer large enough to hold all the points for two cubes.  But you don't seem to know which of these approaches you are using?

Comment: @BenVoigt,  Yes, I don't know how to make my beffers hold  points for 2 cubes. Can you givwe me a link/help how to do this?